# Loading/saving PHP objects to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, object

I have an object for a „listing“, which has attributes like id, name, description, etc. which can be loaded via load($id) method.

It has some advanced attributes, too. For example multiple products (which is a separate object). To improve performance, I load them when you try to access them with listing->getProducts().

Now I want a save method in listing, to save the values back to the MySQL db. But I‘m not sure how to do that product saving in a clean way. 
The best way would be adding a save method to products object and call it from the listing object, but that only saves the values. How do I handle added/removed products? That has to be done by the listing object I think. But how do I know if all products were removed or if they weren't even loaded (because they didn’t get accessed)?

All ways, like storing a boolean loaded products seem like a stupid solution. Do you have a good idea how to handle that? I‘m not inexperienced in coding but I want to improve my structure since I always end in a lot of code mess if projects get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we are talking about adding, editing, and deleting products in your database. So you are probably going to need an 'insert' method and a 'delete' method (invoked from your list view). as well as the 'save' (update) method.

But the problem, or so I understand, is that you don't know which of these to use on a particular product line.

If you are just allowing the user to type willy nilly into input fields, so that you can't tell whether this is an edit, an insert, or a delete (or indeed which product you are editing or deleting, if you allow /every/ field to be changed) then you are making your life really complicated - is this necessary, from a business requirement/UI design perspective?

Consider something like listing the existing information read only and providing edit/insert/delete buttons.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it properly. I have two models, one is called listing which has the attributes id, name, description, products and a method load($id), which fetches the fields id, name and description from the database table "listing".
There is a second method loadProducts(), which loads the products associated with the listing from the products table and stores them (as an array of products) into the products attribute of the listing. Question is: How do I save it after manipulation back to the db? save() method which saves attributes id, name, description is easy.

Comment: Maybe I load a listing with it's products, remove a product from the array, add 2 new ones and call listing->save(). Now I want, that the product and the association from listing_product table gets removed, 2 new products get created and associated in the db. I know the queries and all that stuff, but in which object should I do what? save() method in "product"? But that couldn't do the association to the listing. And how can I prevent from deleting all products when I didn't load them with listing->loadProducts(), since the array would be empty?

Comment: I really think you would be better doing this, especially the database part, at the individual product level - apart from anything else, doing the whole lot at once is surely not scalable (and simultaneous editing sessions by multiple users are going to be really hard to handle). So really what I am saying is 'don't start from here', I'm afraid. (There's a reason why a typical online shopping cart has a remove button on every line rather than letting you edit it away.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a more or less good way on my own.

For the first problem (where to save what):
Storing of basic attributes of listing in the `listing->save()` method,
calling `listing->products[]->save()` to store products details,
syncing the listing<->product associations in `listing->save()`.

Second problem (Deleting products, just because they didn't got load):
That was pretty easy, `listing->products = null` -> not loaded, `listing->products = array()` -> loaded, but empty. (I should got this earlier, haha)